# Ctrl+c in dart console application

Tags: dart

Is there a way to catch <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in dart console application?

For example, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to send clean "closing" packet to web socket clients from server instead of just brutally closing the sockets.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to catch SIGINT for the current in Dart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448306/how-to-catch-sigint-for-the-current-in-dart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a dig around, and I *think* that the answer, at the moment is no.

You can capture stdin, for example:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  stdin.onData = () => print(stdin.read());
}
```

but this does not respond to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Elsewhere, `process.dart` (part of the `dart:io` library) defines various signals, such as SIGQUIT, and an `onExit()` callback, but this is used to control child processes rather than the host process.

Comment: I've reached pretty much the same conclusion. Was hoping that in the host process I could define onExit, but doesn't appear to be so.

Comment: It might be worth raising a feature request on [http://dartbug.com](http://dartbug.com).

Comment: This is now being implemented. [Bug](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15188)

Answer (score 4):

This is now available

I found the following test code at [Unified Diff: tests/standalone/io/signals_test_script.dart](https://codereview.chromium.org/119093007/patch/120001/130013)

```dart
import "dart:io";

void main(args) {
  int usr1Count = int.parse(args[0]);
  int usr2Count = int.parse(args[1]);
  var sub1;
  var sub2;
  void check() {
    if (usr1Count < 0 || usr2Count < 0) exit(1);
    if (usr1Count == 0 && usr2Count == 0) {
      sub1.cancel();
      sub2.cancel();
    }
    print("ready");
  }
  sub1 = ProcessSignal.SIGUSR1.watch().listen((signal) {
    if (signal != ProcessSignal.SIGUSR1) exit(1);
    usr1Count--;
    check();
  });
  sub2 = ProcessSignal.SIGUSR2.watch().listen((signal) {
    if (signal != ProcessSignal.SIGUSR2) exit(1);
    usr2Count--;
    check();
  });
  check();
}
```

Hopefully this will be released soon.

See also [How to catch SIGINT for the current in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448306)