# How to catch SIGINT for the current in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-io

How can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or SIGINT be caught in a Dart program for the current process?

Something similar to this for Node:

```dart
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373706/ctrlc-in-dart-console-application ?

Comment: Doesn't look like that somebody created a feature request at http://dartbug.com/. How about doing it?

Comment: Hadn't seen the other conversation. Thanks for the link. I will have a look at making a feature request.

Comment: Add a star to this [bug](http://dartbug.com/15188).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like the `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` fields used in the old answer are now [deprecated](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.0/dart-io/ProcessSignal/SIGUSR1-constant.html). I got the following example working using the [`sigint`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.0/dart-io/ProcessSignal/sigint-constant.html) field:

```dart
import "dart:io";

void main() {
  var n = 0;
  ProcessSignal.sigint.watch().listen((signal) {
    print(" caught ${++n} of 3");

    if (n == 3) {
      exit(0);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I found the following test code at [Unified Diff: tests/standalone/io/signals_test_script.dart](https://codereview.chromium.org/119093007/patch/120001/130013)

```dart
import "dart:io";

void main(args) {
  int usr1Count = int.parse(args[0]);
  int usr2Count = int.parse(args[1]);
  var sub1;
  var sub2;
  void check() {
    if (usr1Count < 0 || usr2Count < 0) exit(1);
    if (usr1Count == 0 && usr2Count == 0) {
      sub1.cancel();
      sub2.cancel();
    }
    print("ready");
  }
  sub1 = ProcessSignal.SIGUSR1.watch().listen((signal) {
    if (signal != ProcessSignal.SIGUSR1) exit(1);
    usr1Count--;
    check();
  });
  sub2 = ProcessSignal.SIGUSR2.watch().listen((signal) {
    if (signal != ProcessSignal.SIGUSR2) exit(1);
    usr2Count--;
    check();
  });
  check();
}
```